# Apache AllowOverride none doesn't work for sub-directories once All has been applied first

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm not sure what is wrong here, but I have the following conf:

```
    # Root
    <Directory /var/www/xxx/>
            AllowOverride All

            Header always append Directory Home
    </Directory>


    # images
    <Directory /var/www/xxx/images/>
            AllowOverride None

            Order allow,deny
            allow from all

            Header always append Directory images
    </Directory>
```

Inside the root dir I have an .htaccess file, to include it everywhere in the directory.

What I'm trying to do - is to exclude "images" dir from this configuration.
I've added a special header for every directory so I can debug it, and according to the CURL command below - it follow the rules correctly.

```
< HTTP/1.1 401 Authorization Required
< Directory: Home, images
< Last-Modified: Fri, 21 Sep 2012 09:47:28 GMT
< ETag: "9e81e5-4069-20b94c00"
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Content-Length: 16489
< Connection: close
< Content-Type: image/png
```

The problem is that I'm receiving 401 instead of 200OK, according to the headers ( Home, images ) - it first get the "All" and then should overwrite it with "None" - but it doesn't, I'm still receiving the 401, what can be the problem here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the "Satisfy Any" I solved the problem of having no AUTH for a sub-directory

```
<Directory /var/www/xxx/images/>
    allow from all
    Satisfy Any

    Header always append Directory images
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an htaccess file in the parent directory that is requiring authorization and that is getting applied to the `/images/` directory. The `AllowOverride` directive allows directives in an htaccess file, it doesn't remove or disallow anything a parent htaccess file may have.

So if you have:

1. document root directory: `AllowOverride All`
2. document root directory htaccess file: Auth required, valid user

and then:

1. images directory: `AllowOverride None`
2. images directory htaccess: nothing in this file will be applied because of `AllowOverride`

but all the directives in the parent htaccess still apply.

If you want the `/images` directory excluded from requiring auth, you'll need to setup an exclusion in your auth setup in the parent htaccess (or vhost config, or whereever your setup is).

Comment: Thank you, from your answer I actually had a better understanding of the AllowOverride ... though according to the Apache documentation - it should not request and disable if exists - the .htaccess file when there's a "None" value though it's still applied from the root directory.